# ORACLE Trigger - Update on the same table the trigger runs

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger after update that updates the table on which the trigger runs. But I don't know method to choose to bypass the problem with oracle.I've read different opinions and suggestions but I didn't manage to find the best one.Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER monitor
   AFTER UPDATE OF status
   ON action
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   actiontype   NUMBER (10, 0);
   children     NUMBER (10, 0);
BEGIN
   SELECT code_id
     INTO actiontype
     FROM action_type
    WHERE     action_id = :new.action_id
          AND projid = :new.projid
          AND code_id = 'xxxx';

   IF     actiontype = xxxx
      AND :old.status = 'Active'
      AND :new.status = 'Finished'
   THEN
      SELECT t.action_id
        INTO chlidren
        FROM action t
             LEFT JOIN actionrel tp ON t.action_id = tp.action_id
             LEFT JOIN actionactv tsk ON tsk.action_id = t.action_id
             LEFT JOIN project p ON p.projid = t.projid
       WHERE     tp.pred_action_id = :new.action_id
             AND t.status = 'TK_NotStart'
             AND tsk.code_id = 'xxxx'
             AND TRUNC (TO_DATE (p.last_date, 'DD.MON.YYYY')) =
                    TRUNC (TO_DATE (t.target_date, 'DD.MON.YYYY'));

      IF children != NULL
      THEN
         UPDATE action
            SET act_start_date = target_start_date
          WHERE action_id = children;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END;
```

May I receive some hints ? :)

Comment: I would recommend to write a PL/SQL procedure for this. Usually it is not smart to put complex business logic into a trigger, there are too many drawbacks. Prefer triggers mainly for basic stuff like `:NEW.LAST_MODIFY_DATE := SYSDATE;` or `:NEW.ID := ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;`

Comment: Make a procedure based on a simpler trigger?

Comment: No, I mean don't use a trigger at all. Write a procedure which does all the operations.

Comment: But how can I check if the value of status changed from a value in another? I don;t know how to do that in a procedure :)

Comment: When you make a procedure then you don't run any manual `UPDATE` command on this table (in best case revoke the privileges for that), do **everything** inside the procedure, also the update.

Answer (score 0):

Hints? Yes.

In order to fix mutating table problem, you can use

- [a collection in package variable](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions#solution_1),
- [a global temporary table](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions#solution_2), or
- [a compound trigger](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CGRC9SJRBTH83GTAAWUB1H4JG.html) (scroll down to statement #17). This is the simplest option, as far as I can tell

Or, if possible, avoid doing what you're doing. That requires you to change the process, though.